# Articles and books sorted separately - BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

Recently I have encountered a problem with sorting of the content of my Bibliography.
See the picture.

[image]

The first two items are articles, the rest are some books. Somehow, my BibTeX is forced to sort items by author's last name (which is OK), but books and articles are separated. 
I have also tried compilation of blank document (without all unnecessary packages), but the problem still persisted. Change of bibtex style is not working, so it seems is a built-in functionality.
Could it be turned off ?

Edit://
Bibliography is loaded via external file bib.tex, which contains only items like

```
    @BOOK{agarwal,
 author    = {\textsc{Agarwal} R. P.{,}\textsc{Lakshmikantham} V.},
 title     = "{{Uniqueness and Nonuniqueness Criteria for Ordinary Differential Equations}}",
 publisher = "World Scientific",
 year      =  1993,
}

@ARTICLE {peral,
    author   = "{\textsc{Peral} I.{,} \textsc{Velázguez} J. J. L. }",
    title    = "{{On the Stability or Instability of the Singular Solution of the Semilinear Heat Equation with Exponential Reaction Term}}",
    journal  = "Arch. Rational Mech. Anal.",
    year     = 1995,
    volume   = "129",
    pages    = "201-224",
}

@ARTICLE {mines,
    author   = "{\textsc{Singh} R. V. K. }",
    title    = "{{Spontaneous heating and fire in coal mines}}",
    journal  = "Procedia Engineering",
    year     = 2013,
    volume   = "62",
    pages    = "78-90",
}
```

and so on.
This bibtex file is then loaded inside the document with

```
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{bib}
```

As I have said, the problem is still here even in blank document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Don't format the authors in the bib. The correct input for e.g. `"{\textsc{Singh} R. V. K. }"` is `{Singh, R. V. K. }` and `{\textsc{Agarwal} R. P.{,}\textsc{Lakshmikantham} V.}` should be `{Agarwal, R. P. and Lakshmikantham, V.}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output has nothing to do with articles and books, but only with how the author names have been input.

```
@BOOK{agarwal,
 author    = {Agarwal, R. P. and Lakshmikantham, V.},
 title     = {{Uniqueness and Nonuniqueness Criteria for Ordinary Differential Equations}},
 publisher = {World Scientific},
 year      =  1993,
}

@ARTICLE {peral,
    author   = {Peral, I. and Vel{\'a}zguez, J. J. L.},
    title    = {{On the Stability or Instability of the Singular Solution of the Semilinear Heat Equation with Exponential Reaction Term}},
    journal  = {Arch. Rational Mech. Anal.},
    year     = 1995,
    volume   = {129},
    pages    = {201-224},
}

@ARTICLE {mines,
    author   = {Singh, R. V. K.},
    title    = {{Spontaneous heating and fire in coal mines}},
    journal  = {Procedia Engineering},
    year     = 2013,
    volume   = {62},
    pages    = {78-90},
}
```

Using small caps for typesetting names is a job for the style file, which is actually done by `siam.bst`.

Full example, where `filecontents` is used for making it self-contained. You can use your separate `.bib` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{agarwal,
 author    = {Agarwal, R. P. and Lakshmikantham, V.},
 title     = {{Uniqueness and Nonuniqueness Criteria for Ordinary Differential Equations}},
 publisher = {World Scientific},
 year      =  1993,
}

@ARTICLE {peral,
    author   = {Peral, I. and Vel{\'a}zguez, J. J. L.},
    title    = {{On the Stability or Instability of the Singular Solution of the Semilinear Heat Equation with Exponential Reaction Term}},
    journal  = {Arch. Rational Mech. Anal.},
    year     = 1995,
    volume   = {129},
    pages    = {201-224},
}

@ARTICLE {mines,
    author   = {Singh, R. V. K.},
    title    = {{Spontaneous heating and fire in coal mines}},
    journal  = {Procedia Engineering},
    year     = 2013,
    volume   = {62},
    pages    = {78-90},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{mines,agarwal,peral}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, should I use a comma to separate authors ? Would "{ ,} " work ? I would really need to overcome the "and" separator.

Comment: @MartinKaisler `and` is the keyword for separating authors; the bib style then decides what to do.